# Como puedo imprimir los numeros impares en un bucle while? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo este código:

```
numero=0

while numero<100:
    numero= numero+1
    if numero%2:
        print(numero)
```

Pero si intento usar `print(sum(numero))` me tira un error

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de 0 a 49 y usas la siguiente fórmula 2 * i + 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber si un numero es impar, tenes que dividirlo entre 2 y si el resto es distinto de 0 el numero es impar, a tu código le hace falta un ligero cambio:

```
while numero<100:
    numero+=1
    if numero%2 != 0: #Si el resto de dividir numero entre 2 es distinto de 0
        print(numero)
```

Si lo que quieres es sumar todos los numeros impares del 1 al 100, tienes que guardarlos en un array y recien ahi podras utilizar la funcion sum(), ya que esta recibe un objeto iterable como parametro.

Si lo que quieres es lo anterior mencionado el código podria quedar asi:

```
numeros = []

numero = 0
while numero<100:
    numero+=1
    if numero%2 != 0:
        numeros.append(numero)#Añade el numero al array
print(sum(numeros)) #Imprime la suma de todos los elementos del array
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que le falta es si

```
If numero%2!=0
```

Comment: Igual  es mejor que publiques todo tu codigo porque hay dice print(sum(numero)),supongo que sum es lo de primo pero quizas no